# Orthogonal complement of $S = \left\{u\in L^2(0,1) \ : \ u(x) = 0 \ \text{ for } \ 0 < x < \frac{1}{2} \right\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

How do I determine the orthogonal in $L^2(0,1)$ of the set 
$$
S = \left\{u\in L^2(0,1) \ : \ u(x) = 0 \ \text{for} \ 0 < x < \frac{1}{2} \right\}?
$$

Comment: I had tried something similar to the answer given below, but it seems I left out some details which I've fixed in my notes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand\inner[2]{\left\langle #1, #2 \right\rangle}$

Let $f \in S^\perp$.

For arbitrary $u \in S$ we have:
$$0 = \inner{f}{u} = \int_0^1 f(t)\overline{u(t)}\diff{t} = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\overline{u(t)}\diff{t} + \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 f(t)\overline{u(t)}\diff{t} = \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 f(t)\overline{u(t)}\diff{t} = \inner{f |_{\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}}{u |_{\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}}_{L^2\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}$$
where $\inner{}{}_{L^2\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}$ denotes the inner product on the $L^2\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)$ space.

Now notice that $f\mathbb{1}_\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right) \in S$ so:
$$0 = \inner{f|_{\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}}{f|_{\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}}_{L^2\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)}$$
which implies $f|_{\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)} = 0$, or equivalently $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in \left\langle \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right\rangle$.

So far we have shown that $S^\perp$ is contained in the subspace
$$T = \left\{v\in L^2(0,1) \ : \ v(x) = 0, \forall x \in \left\langle \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right\rangle \right\}
$$

By analogous computation we get $T \subseteq S^\perp$, so we have $S^\perp = T$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!